# A and B toss a fair die, until one of them gets 6. The person who gets 6 is given 50 coins as a reward. How much is A willing to pay to play first?

Tags: probability

As the title says, A and B throw fair dice with faces numbered 1 to 6 until one of them gets a 6. I am able to derive the probability of A winning if A starts first as $P(A) = 6/11$.

From my understanding, since A has more chances of winning than B if A starts first, then A should pay the full 50 coins. But the answer says $50 \times(6/11 - 5/11) = 50/11$. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: If $A$ pays $50$ coins, the best $A$ can do is break even, and sometime $A$ will lose $50$ coins.  That's not rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering a question you need to understand what the question is.  You ask what A should pay to play first, but what happens if he doesn't pay?  To get the answer you are looking for, A and B are going to play the game and the question is who goes first.  If you go second your expected value is $\frac 5{11} \cdot 50 = \frac {250}{11}$.  If you go first your expected value is $\frac 6{11} \cdot 50 = \frac {300}{11}$.  If you pay less than $\frac {50}{11}$ your expected value is increased by paying.  If you pay exactly that much your expected value does not change, so it doesn't matter whether you pay or not.  If you are asked to pay more, you should decline as your expected value will be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

**Play first**: represent payoff by the r.v. $\text{P}_1(c)=(50-c,-c)$ with probability $(6/11,5/11)$ with $c$  being the cost of playing first.

**Play second**: represent payoff by the r.v. $\text{P}_2=(50,0)$ with probabilities $(5/11,6/11)$.

If you pay $c=50$ to play first, your payoff will be  $\text{P}_1(50)=(50-50,-50)=(0,-50)$ with probabilities $(6/11,5/11)$, clearly a bad deal compared to $\text{P}_2=(50,0)$ with probabilities $(5/11,6/11)$, as @Robert Shore correctly pointed out in the comments.

As for the amount $c$, $A$ is willing to pay to play first, that is not an easy question. Depends on $A$'s preferences. Under an often used approach first introduced by Daniel Bernoulli, called nowadays "Expected Utility Paradigm" (EUP), individual $A$ would weakly prefer playing first for any $c\ge 0$ such that:
$$E[u(P_1(c))]\ge E[u(P_2)]\Leftrightarrow u(50-c)\frac{6}{11}+u(-c)\frac{5}{11}\ge u(50)\frac{5}{11}+u(0)\frac{6}{11},$$
in which $E[\cdot]$ is the expected value operator and $u(x)$ is an utility function that represents individual $A$'s preferences. The value $c=c^*$ such that $$E[u(P_1(c^*))]=E[u(P_2)]\ \ \ (\text{eq.} 1)$$ is often called "willingness to pay" to play first in a situation like that, under the EUP.

If $u(x)=x$, that is individual $A$ decides using the mean as the rule, then $c^*=\frac{50}{11}\approx 4.5455$, the proposed solution in your problem. But it is not a requirement. Using this utility function to represent preferences might lead to problematic situations such as [St. Petersbourg Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox), clearly understood since Bernoulli´s time.

Therefore, a more exact answer to the "willing to pay" part of our question depends on better definition of $A$'s preferences. If, for instance, $u(x)=\ln(x+100)$, a typical utility function proposed by Bernoulli, representing declining marginal utility, the value of $c^*$ that solves (eq. 1) will be given by:
$$c^*\approx 4.4197<\frac{50}{11}\approx 4.5455.$$